# jQuery toggleClass doesn't fire work resizing browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with some code. Basically on click of a div the class 'active-sort' should be added/removed (This class changes the position of .sort-by from the top). On page load it works great but for some reason the toggleClass doesn't always work when the browser is resized (sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't).

I'm not great with this, so was hoping a new set of eyes might be able to instantly see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function toggleSortBy() {
  var toggle = $('.sort-banner-row'),
      sortBy = $('.sort-by');

  if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    toggle.click(function(){
      sortBy.toggleClass('active-sort');
    });
  } else {
    // other code here for smaller devices
  }
};

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  toggleSortBy();
});
```

Comment: this event fires really really fast you should probably start by debouncing / rate limiting the event, theres a good article here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/

Comment: Thanks for this, would the fact it fires fast be why it's intermittent? I've tried implementing but it doesn't seem to have any impact. Which part of this exactly is the issue? Is it the click event or?

Comment: binding events inside a event handler is a BAD IDEA

Comment: Well, one issue is that this code is going to add loads of different (although identical) `click` listeners to the `.sort-banner-row` when you resize the window.

Comment: I can't say for sure that it's your problem but have experience similar problems due to this. Yeah if you throw a console.log in and start resizing the window you'll see the event can fire several times over before the one callback completes. debouncing this event is the best starting point, and will either solve the problem or make the problem easier to diagnose.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Would you mind explaining to me why it does that, I'm really trying to learn and would like to understand?

Comment: Robin also makes a good point about the click, you'll be binding a new click event each time the resize event fires. Each time the click method is bound its adding a new click event declaration so one click could fire several bindings.

Comment: @user2498890 it's because you are adding that event listener (which is what jQuery's `.click(...)` does) every time a resize event fires. As @digital-pollution said, this happens really fast when the user resizes the window - but even if you put some rate limiting in, you're still going to end up with multiple listeners there, which will soon slow your UI right down and probably lead to your toggle firing too many times. (If it happens an even number of times you won't even see it.) Event listeners should generally only be set once, when the page first loads or the element is first added.

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone for their input and explaining.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible you may not need the resize event since you're checking the window size already in the click handler

```
var toggle = $('.sort-banner-row'),
    sortBy = $('.sort-by');

toggle.click(function(){

  if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
     sortBy.toggleClass('active-sort');
  } else {
    // other code here for smaller devices
  }
});
```

but if you do you should debounce the resize event
//css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event

then you could do something like:

```
var toggle = $('.sort-banner-row'),
    sortBy = $('.sort-by'),
    isMobile = false;

toggle.click(function(){
  if (isMobile) {
     sortBy.toggleClass('active-sort');
  } else {
    // other code here for smaller devices
  }
});

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  // don't forget to debounce you'll see why later on in your development.
  isMobile = ($(window).width() > 1024) ? false : true;
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, I do need the resize event as the JS changes at mobile. Anyway, I'm going to look into the debounce alongside your example. Really appreciate you taking the time to explain.

Comment: no worries hopefully theres enough there you get you going :)